# Contador en React - Error: Too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs, contador, usestate

estoy haciendo un ejercicio simple en React de crear un contador utilizando useState. Al presionar el boton, se debe mostrar en el Html el contador sumando +1 por cada click. Al ejecutar el codigo me dice que hay un tipo de bucle que se ejecuta antes de yo poder hacer click en el boton. No entiendo porque pasa esto.

```js
import {useState } from 'react';

function Contador() {
 
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>

     <h1>Contador</h1>


     <h1>{contador}</h1>
     
     <button  onClick={setContador(contador+1)} >Contar +1</button>



    </>
  );
}

export default Contador;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que al hacerse el render de React se esta ejecutando `setContador`, una y otra vez. Es decir, la forma en la que actualmente tienes tu código ejecuta el código de `onClick` desde el render y no cuando tu presionas el botón.

Para corregir el error, debes modificar el código del botón para que ejecute el `setContador` al ser presionado.

Él código debería quedar como:

```
<button onClick={() => setContador(contador+1)}>Contar + 1</button>
```